# How to Sync Chrome extension Storage.local when storage.sync exceeded Quota

Tags: google-chrome-extension, storage

As the title says, I want to sync chrome extension storage data across devices. I was using the `storage.sync` method till now. But today I got a new error message as follows:

```
    Unchecked runtime.lastError: QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded
```

After few googling, I found that storage.sync has limited quota and we need to use storage.local instead. But the problem is how do I sync data between devices while using storage.local.

Please help.

Sample Code:

```
    chrome.storage.sync.set({tasks, function(storage) {
        // do something
      });
    }
```

Comment: `local` is local, it can't be synced using the API so you'll have to use an external service like dropbox or google drive, onedrive and so on. You can also apply compression to your `sync` storage e.g. LZString library.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot use `chrome.local` to sync between devices.

However the issue appears to be the item size is too large `QUOTA_BYTES_PER_ITEM quota exceeded`.
Please note that this quota is significantly smaller than the total amount (in bytes) of data you can store using `chrome.sync`.

Reference: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync

I would recommend trying to break up your items into smaller chunks and using `chrome.sync`for each of the smaller set of items.

You could also consider integrating your extension with a cloud database service to allow a larger set of storage capabilities.